# How to make citeyearpar command a clickable hyperlink in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, citing

Consider the following MWE, with a `.tex` file made of:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames},hyperref={colorlinks,allcolors=Blue}]{beamer}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,natbib,hyperref=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{References.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\citet{serrano} is a great paper!
\citeauthor{serrano}'s \citeyearpar{serrano} paper is great!
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And a `.bib` file called `References.bib` containing

```
@article{serrano,
   author = "Roberto Serrano",
   title = "Reinterpreting the Kernel",
   journal = "Journal of Economic Theory",
   volume = "77",
   number = "1",
   pages = "58 -- 80",
   year = "1997",
   url = "https://doi.org/10.1006%2Fjeth.1997.2314"
}
```

As you can see in the image below, using `\citet{serrano}` produces a clickable blue link. However, using `\citeauthor{serrano}'s \citeyearpar{serrano}` does not. It looks inconsistent and, apparently, I can't sort this on my own. Hence, **could anyone please tell me how make `\citeyearpar{serrano}` clickable and therefore blue?**

[image]

PS: I place this question in Beamer because this behavior does not seem to occur neither in standard articles nor KOMA Script ones (at least not with my current full preamble).

Thank you all very much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you need to add the following code:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearpar}
    {}
    {\mkbibparens{\bibhyperref{\printdate}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}
```

With the complete MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{serrano,
   author = "Roberto Serrano",
   title = "Reinterpreting the Kernel",
   journal = "Journal of Economic Theory",
   volume = "77",
   number = "1",
   pages = "58 -- 80",
   year = "1997",
   url = "https://doi.org/10.1006%2Fjeth.1997.2314"
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[%
  xcolor={svgnames},
  hyperref={colorlinks,allcolors=Blue}
]{beamer}

\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear-comp,
  backend=biber,
  natbib,
  hyperref=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearpar}
    {}
    {\mkbibparens{\bibhyperref{\printdate}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\citet{serrano} is a great paper!
\citeauthor{serrano}'s \citeyearpar{serrano} paper is great!
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

you get what you want:

[image]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/463294/35864. In this case I would strongly prefer `\parencite*`.