# How to force \citeyearpar to show (year letter) instead of just (year)?

Tags: biblatex

Consider the following MWE, with a `.tex` file as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,natbib,hyperref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

\begin{document}

\citet{binmore} is an earlier chapter than \citet{binmore2} is.

\citeauthor{binmore}'s \citeyearpar{binmore} chapter is an earlier one than \citet{binmore2} is.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And a `.bib` file containing:

```
@inbook{binmore,
    title = "Nash Bargaining Theory I, II, III",
    author = "{Kenneth G.} Binmore",
    booktitle = "The Economics of Bargaining",
    publisher = "Oxford: Blackwell",
    editor = "{Kenneth G.} Binmore and Partha Dasgupta",
    pages = "27 -- 46, 61 -- 76, 239 -- 256",
    year = "1987"
}

@inbook{binmore2,
    title = "Perfect equilibria in bargaining models",
    author = "{Kenneth G.} Binmore",
    booktitle = "The Economics of Bargaining",
    publisher = "Oxford: Blackwell",
    editor = "{Kenneth G.} Binmore and Partha Dasgupta",
    pages = "77 -- 105",
    year = "1987"
}
```

As you can see in the output below, the `\citeyearpar{binmore}` entry does not show (1987a); instead it shows (1987).

[image]

In my opinion, this is inconsistent and may lead to confusion. Therefore, **how can I get `\citeyeapar{...}` to show (1987a) instead of just (1987)?**

Thank you all very much in advanced for your time.

Comment: I'd use `\citeauthor{binmore}'s \parencite*{binmore}`. The advantage is that you will get the hyperlink for free.

Comment: The braces in `author = "{Kenneth G.} Binmore",` should not be necessary, `author = "Kenneth G. Binmore",` should do the same. If you want to be sure, you can of course use `author = "Binmore, Kenneth G.",`. I would also split the `publisher = "Oxford: Blackwell",` into `location = {Oxford}, publisher = {Blackwell},`

Comment: @moewe Your solution works just fine: feel free to post it as answer for me to accept it (in fact, I'm likely to change all `\cityearpar{...}` for `parencite*{...}` for the free hyperlink... Any downside?). Regarding your second comment: even if unnecessary, are the braces `{...}` wrong? I only use them whenever `biblatex` (or something else) may get confused between what belongs to the name and what to the surname. And finally... OK: I'll split the location as well! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: `biblatex` knows how to split names like `Kenneth G. Binmore` and so `{Kenneth G.} Binmore` is really not necessary (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864). Indeed it will change the initials produced by Biber (the former gives "K. G. Binmore", the latter only "K. Binmmore"). In general I would avoid unnecessary braces wherever possible (there were some recent issues like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414685/35864 caused by unnecessary braces).

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232580/35864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `authoryear`- and `autortitle`-like styles usually define starred versions of `\cite` and `\parencite` (i.e. `\cite*` and `\parencite*`) that can omit the name in citations and only print the year or title. The advantage of using this command over `\citeyear` or `\citetitle` is that the starred cite commands add a link and that switching between styles is easier.

Note that with the `natbib` compatibility mode the starred version of the `natbib` names is different from their long names. So we need to use `\parencite*{binmore}` and can't use `\citep*{binmore}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,natbib]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{binmore,
  title     = {Nash Bargaining Theory {I}, {II}, {III}},
  author    = {Kenneth G. Binmore},
  booktitle = {The Economics of Bargaining},
  publisher = {Blackwell},
  location  = {Oxford},
  editor    = {Kenneth G. Binmore and Partha Dasgupta},
  pages     = {27-46, 61-76, 239-256},
  year      = {1987},
}
@inbook{binmore2,
  title     = {Perfect equilibria in bargaining models},
  author    = {Kenneth G. Binmore},
  booktitle = {The Economics of Bargaining},
  publisher = {Blackwell},
  location  = {Oxford},
  editor    = {Kenneth G. Binmore and Partha Dasgupta},
  pages     = {77-105},
  year      = {1987},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\citet{binmore} is an earlier chapter than \citet{binmore2} is.

\citeauthor{binmore}'s \parencite*{binmore} chapter is an earlier one than \textcite{binmore2} is.

\citeauthor{binmore}'s \citep*{binmore}. % oops

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Binmore (1987a) is an earlier chapter than Binmore (1987b) is.//Binmore’s (1987a) chapter is an earlier one than Binmore (1987b) is.//Binmore’s (Binmore, 1987a).]